# Make vim highlight shell scripts at first try

Tags: shell-script, shell, vim

I create a lot of shell scripts with VIM. But since they don't have an extension, VIM doesn't highlight the syntax at first try.

[image]

So I have to write `#!/bin/bash` and exit VIM and open it again to have it highlight the syntax.

[image]

Is it possible to let VIM know in advance that the file I'm creating is a shell script without having to specify an extension (e.g. `.bash`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to write `#!/bin/bash` and exit VIM and open it again

No, after you *save* the file once, just run `:e` without closing Vim. It'll re-read the file, triggering filetype detection.

> Is it possible to let VIM know in advance that the file I'm creating is a shell script without having to specify an extension (e.g. `.bash`)?

You could do one of:

```
vim -c 'set ft=sh' some-file
vim +'set ft=sh' some-file
```